# Keyboard shortcuts in Eclipse on ubuntu 18

Tags: eclipse, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

when pressing alt shift in eclipse it changes the layout as (alt+shift) is the shortcut to change the language, any other shortcut start with alt shift change the layout and execute the shortcut. is there anyway to solve this conflict and only execute the shortcut? maybe to act only on key release?

it worked on ubuntu 14 (i recently updated to 18)

Comment: What about changing the shortcut to switch the keyboard layout in Ubuntu? https://askubuntu.com/a/1029605/721289

Comment: changing the shortcut wont solve the issue...

Comment: Why is changing the shortcut for the layout (Alt+Shift) not solving the problem?